# tts set voice using vocalize tts engine

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I am trying to implement a tts application using vocalizer voices. I have downloaded a lot of the voices and they are listed correctly with the get Voices call.

```
 for(Voice v : engine.getVoices()){
 }
```

But when I call `engine.setVoice(v)` it is not set correctly when you have more than one voice downloaded for a language. e.g.

[image]

Instead of using the selected voice in the application (Fiona) it will instead use Kate, if I swap the favorited voice in the vocalizer app it will use Fiona instead of Kate. This is the same if you have all the voices downloaded it will always pick the favorited one for the local of the voice that was selected in the app.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the result of `setVoice()`? I've found that no TTS provider is handling the new Voice APIs correctly, other than Google...

Comment: 0, it is the one for success, -1 is ERROR

Comment: In the Android Text to Speech Settings, are the voices listed as separate engines?

Comment: No they are all in the "es.codefactory.vocalizertts" engine

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and can confirm that it's a bug.

As you say, it will successfully switch between voices of different Locales, but it will default to the 'favourite' selected in the application, when attempting to call `setVoice())` on one of the same Locale.

It's also frustrating that when calling `getVoice()` it returns the voice you attempted to set, so there is no way to detect it 'failed'. It must be changing it internally on each call to `speak`

I'm about to report the bug using the email in the About Settings and reference this post - be good if you could do the same!

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed on Vocalizer version 2.0.7 (Aug 7th 2017).

There is an option inside the app settings called "Support latest TTS API" or something similar that is enabled by default.

Changelog:

IMPORTANT: This update uses new voice data and current voices will be deleted. You will have to download the voices again

-Upgraded engine to Nuance Vocalizer Embedded 3.0 improving quality and stability

-8 new languages: Chilean, Bhojpuri, Bengali, Kannada, Marathi, Telugu, Tamil and Croatian

-20 new voices

-Code optimization to improve response time

**-Support for Android TextToSpeech API**

-Support for Android 7 Nougat

-Support for new emojis Unicode 8.0 and 9.0

-Internal improvements and bugfixes